# SQL: Return from group within table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create an SQL Query in MS Access from a table where it has a profile and many users and be able to identify which profiles don't have a specific user.

Example 
I am want to return the **profiles** that **don't** contain the user **UserA**

**Profile table**

```
Profile     User
A           UserA
A           UserB
A           UserC
A           UserD
B           UserB
B           UserC
C           UserA
D           UserV
```

**Output**

```
Profile
B
D
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.profile
from profile as p
group by p.profile
having sum(iif(p.user = "UserA", 1, 0)) = 0;
```

Comment: FWIW, the `having` clause could be reduced to `having sum(p.user = "UserA") = 0` yielding the same result, albeit less readable.

Comment: @LeeMac . . . That is totally readable, I just don't think it is syntactically valid in MS Access.

Comment: It is, as True/False is represented by the integers `-1` & `0` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct profile from tablename as t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename as tt
  where tt.profile = t.profile and user = 'UserA'  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can also use a join:

```
select distinct t1.profile
from YourTable t1 left join 
(select t2.profile as p from YourTable t2 where t2.user = "UserA") t3 on t1.profile = t3.p
where t3.p is null
```

Or `not in`:

```
select distinct t1.profile
from YourTable t1
where t1.profile not in (select t2.profile from YourTable t2 where t2.user = "UserA")
```

Change `YourTable` to the name of your table.